# Properly used NSGetExecutablePath

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, parameters

I try to get the path to my application at runtime. I found some old sources from C and converted it accordingly to the functions parameter type definition:

```
var path = [Int8] (count:1024, repeatedValue: 0)
var bufsize : UInt32 = 1024

if _NSGetExecutablePath(&path, &bufsize) == 0 {
println("executable path is \(path)")
}
```

It runs, but I need an Int8 array, not a string. So I have to search for the end of the character chain and convert it back to a string. What is the correct way to use this function in SWIFT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a Swift String from a C String

```
let executablePath = String(CString: path, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
println("executable path is \(executablePath)")
```

But there is an easier way to get the path to the executable

```
let executablePath = Bundle.main.executablePath!
```

Comment: That's incredibly! Thank you very much. I searched a lot but never found a hint to NSBundle.mainBundle().executablePath!

Comment: If you regard the answer as correct, please accept it.

Comment: I did it, but was forced to wait, because there is a minimum time delay before accepting it!

Comment: In swift4: it's `Bundle.main.executablePath`

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4

```
let executablePath = Bundle.main.executablePath!
print(executablePath)
```