# How to get the running program path in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos

I developed a **Swift** program for **Mac OS**, and put the program and data in one USB. When I plug the USB into a Mac, open the USB folder and run the program, the program will read the data in USB, but I don't know how to get the data path in program.

In Windows **C#**, I can use the following command:

```
String programPath = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
to get the program path(ex. F:\), and then I can use the path to get the data path(ex. F:\Data).
```

Dose anyone know how to do the same thing in Swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/32090514/1187415.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get the path to the executable with

```
let programPath = Bundle.main.executablePath
```

or the path to the bundle itself with

```
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.bundlePath
```

but this is the path to the executable in the bundle or to the bundle, not the enclosing volume.

To get the enclosing volume use the URL related API

```
let bundleURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL
let parentVolumeURL = try! bundleURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeURLKey]).volume
```

Comment: Why not use `Bundle.main.bundlePath` then, it will give you path to the bundle folder itself. And it's not optional too, unlike `.executablePath`

Comment: @user28434 Right, thanks, I added your suggestion as a second option.

Comment: Thanks to vadian and user28434, you really did me a big favor.